# Returning data from foreach data

Tags: c#

I am trying to return that data from the foreach "hostedId" Can someone help?

```
public static string GetHostedRecordSet()
{
    var request = new ListHostedZonesRequest()
    {
        MaxItems = "1"
    };

    var list = client.ListHostedZones(request);

    foreach (var hostedId in list.HostedZones)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Hosted ID is:");
        Console.Write(hostedId.Id);
    }

    return hostedId;
}
```

Comment: You have two completely different questions. The first is "Unclear what you're asking", and the second is "Primarily Opinion Based"

Comment: @krillgar ok I've just updated it one question and tried to make the question simple. Hope that helps

Comment: @user3622142 Do you only expect one entry to be in `HostedZones` ? If there are multiple do you want to retrun the first ? The last ? All of them concatenated with a ',' ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I want to return all the all if thats possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all values as a single string you can concatenate them with a delimiter, such as `','`:

```
public static string GetHostedRecordSet()
{
    var request = new ListHostedZonesRequest()
    {
        MaxItems = "1"
    };

    var list = client.ListHostedZones(request);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var hostedId in list.HostedZones)
    {
        result.Append(hostedId.Id).Append(",");
    }

    return result.ToString(0, Math.Max(0, result.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you want to return the first element:

```
return list.HostedZones.First().Id; // Not in a loop!
```

If you want to return several items, change the signature of the method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetHostedRecordSet()
{
    var request = new ListHostedZonesRequest()
    {
        MaxItems = "1"
    };

    var list = client.ListHostedZones(request);
    return list.HostedZones
        .Select(z => z.Id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to figure out this for days.

Comment: If you want to know more about this, search for "LINQ tutorial" in a seach engine on the web.

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but i got this error: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Amazon.Route53.Model.HostedZone,System.String]. I beleive this error is because there is more than one value in the list? Im so confused. If I foreach through list and have a console output it would display the information if that helps.

Comment: This is not the error, it's just the type involved in the error. Please post the error message. Of what type is `Id`? If it is a `int`, then change the return type accordingly (`IEnumerable<int>`).